# Thymeleaf form not submitting to Spring boot controller

Tags: forms, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf, form-submit

I am trying to submit a form to Spring boot controller
This is the thymeleaf part:

```
  <form th:action="@{/change_password}" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 register-right">
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                    <h3 class="register-heading">Change password</h3>
                    <div class="row register-form">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" th:name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" >
                                <span th:if="${notPresent}" class="alert alert-info" style="color:red; width: 100% !important; border: none; background-color: transparent !important;">This email does not exist!</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" th:name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password *" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" th:name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control"  placeholder="Confirm *" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="submit" class="btnRegister" style="background-color: #ffa600 !important;" value="Change"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

This is the Spring boot controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/change_password")
    public String changeUserPassword(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        String path = "";
        User u = userService.findByEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        if(u == null || u.getActive() == 0) {
            model.addAttribute("notPresent", true);
            path =  "redirect:/forgot_password";
        } else {
            u.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("password")));
            userService.updateUser(u);
            sendEmail(u.getEmail(), u.getFirstname());
            path = "redirect:/login";
        }
        
        return path;
    }
```

I don't get any errors so I am not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Is the call reaching the controller method? Is there any RequestMapping defined at the controller class level?

Comment: No, the call does not reach the controller method.  The RequestMapping is defined "@PostMapping("/change_password")"

Comment: I meant if there is any RequestMapping defined overall at the class level. In that case it also has to be appended in the form URL. Anyway, i tried your html and controller code and call reached the controller. Just make sure to check in the browser Network tab if any URL was attempted.

Comment: No there's no overall RequestMapping. I will try to see if there's any other problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit a form you can use an object userPassword define in a Class like this:

```
package ....
imports ....
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class UserPassword {

  private Integer id;
  private String password;
  ... other fields you need
}
```

You add this object to the controller displaying the page with :

```
 model.addAttribute("UserPassword", userPassword);
```

Then you add this object to your form:

```
<form th:action="@{/change_password}" th:object="${userPassword}" method="post">
```

You need to bind data to this object in your html page (here I bind *password* from *userPassword* to the input tag):

```
 <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password *" >
```

And Finnaly I retrieve the object in the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/change_password")
public String changeUserPassword(Model model, @ModelAttribute UserPassword userPassword) {
.....
}
```

You can find a complete tutorial on part 7 from  https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

Comment: Yes, this works. In my case, I did not want to create a new object class that's why I did not try this. Anyway, the problem was that I had not defined the method as accessible in the Security Configurations. I am marking this as a valid answer in case someone needs it later.