# How to get and store value selected from dropdown to the database?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, crud, enterprise

addMission.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Create a mission</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Create a Mission</h1>

<form action="/createMission" method="post">

<p>Mission title: <input type="text" required id="title" name="title" value=""></p>

<p>
<select name="agent" id="agent">
    <option value="natasha">Natasha Romanova</option>
    <option value="austin">Austin Powers</option>
    <option value="johnny">Johnny English</option>
</select>
</p>

<h2>Enter the gadgets</h2>

<p>Gadget 1:<input type="text" required id="gadget1" name="gadget1" value=""></p>
<p>Gadget 2:<input type="text" required id="gadget2" name="gadget2" value=""></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Create Mission!"></p>
</form>
<p> <a href="/"> Back to home </a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller Code

```
    @PostMapping("/createMission")
    public String createMission(@ModelAttribute Mission mission) {

        int returnValue = database.createMission(mission);

        System.out.println(returnValue);

        return "view_missions";
}
```

createMission() method

```
public int createMission(Mission mission) {
    
    MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    String query = "INSERT INTO missions(agent, title, gadget1, gadget2) VALUES (:agent, :title, :gadget1, :gadget2)";
    
    namedParameters
    .addValue("agent", mission.getAgent())
    .addValue("title", mission.getTitle())
    .addValue("gadget1", mission.getGadget1())
    .addValue("gadget2", mission.getGadget2());
    
    int returnValue = jdbc.update(query, namedParameters);
    
    return returnValue;
}
```

In the code snippets shared above, Im creating a mission using thymleaf.
When I enter the details in the textboxes and hit "Create" button I get an error 'Property or field 'empty' cannot be found on null'. Im sure this null property is coming from the dropdown list.
Is there any way I can get the value of the dropdown too along with the other values and send them to the createMission() ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your controller how you get back the values.
You need to add an object to your model in your "get controller" and link it to the form.
Then you can retrieve it and save it in the database.

Please have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990222/thymeleaf-form-not-submitting-to-spring-boot-controller/63994914#63994914) you will get more details on how to make it